# How do you use multiple formsets in a single view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to use multiple formsets using custom forms for a single view. I understand that you need to prefix the formsets so that they don't conflict with each other. However, when I try to prefix the formsets, a ValidationError gets raised.

The way I'm creating the formsets is by passing a list of forms to the view, then making a list of FormSets with formset_factory. Then I create a list of the initialized formsets.

Here is my code:

```py
def edit_stuff2(request, business_id, template_name="business/edit_info.html",
                *args, **kwargs):
    business = BusinessDoc.get(business_id)
    FormSets=[]
    formsets=[]
    info_forms = [(EmailDocForm,'emails'), (URLDocForm,'urls')]
    for form in info_forms:
        FormSets.append(formset_factory(form[0], max_num =0,
                                        can_delete=True, extra=1))
    if request.user:
        if request.method == "POST":
            for FormSet,tup in zip(FormSets,info_forms):
                FormSet.form = staticmethod(curry(tup[0], business))
                formsets.append(FormSet(request.POST,prefix=tup[1],
                                        initial = business[tup[1]]))
                if formsets[-1].is_valid():
                    for form in formsets[-1].forms:
                        form.save()
                        #request.user.message_set.create(message=u"Check it")
            formsets = []
            for FormSet, tup in zip(FormSets, info_forms):
                FormSet.form = staticmethod(curry(tup[0], business))
                formsets.append(FormSet(prefix=tup[1], initial=business[tup[1]]))
        return direct_to_template(request, template=template_name,
                       extra_context={'business': business,
                                      'formsets': formsets,
                                      'info_type': info_type})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

Comment: I think you better edit and format the code so it will make it easier for others to read, thus you will get a good answer for your question.

Comment: sorry about that. totally forgot about formatting it.

Comment: It's a little difficult to follow your sample code -- consider more-descriptive identifiers (*e.g.* the name of the function itself), as well as following [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide, more closely.